# How to lower the file size of a GIF file?

Tags: rendering, gif, kdenlive

I am using [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek) for screen recording into a GIF file.

Sometimes I want to remove useless part of the file. For this purpose I use [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/).

After editing and rendering a final file become much bigger in size than original.

For some reason the default rendering pop-up has disabled quality settings. See screenshot below:

[image]

I don't know how to enable this setting.

Please help me enable quality settings for a GIF file. What kind of tools should I use for editing a GIF files?

Comment: Gif doesn't offer a good compression level for video recording. Maybe you should try another format like mp4, webp, webm. I also record the screen on Windows with Camtasia, if I want to make small animations that should repeat itself on a forum for example I still use gif but otherwise I have to record the video on *.mp4. Here is a gif example: https://i.imgur.com/C0x3869.gif

Comment: GIF uses lossless compression, so you can’t tweak the quality/compression level. The only options you have for limiting file size are resolution (rescale) or choosing a format that supports different quality levels.

Comment: Thanks for all of you for the clarification about GIF